# Simultaneously accessing two arrays in react

Tags: reactjs

I have this portion of code mentioned below, 'msg' and 'botMsg' are two different array of objects. Let say the dummy content of 'msg' and 'botMsg' be:

```
 msg : [ {id: 1, content: 'hello' }, {id: 2, content: 'world'} ]
 botMsg : [{id: 3 content: 'yes'}, {id: 6, content: 'hii'} ]
```

Given both the arrays are of equal length how can i display 'botMsg' content in the second span tag mentioned. i want to alternatively display the 'botMsg' content after every 'msg' content (which i have displayed in first span tag).

```
const Msg = ({ msg, botMsg }) => { 

    const msgList = msg.length ? (
    msg.map((i,j) => {
        return(
            <span>
            <div key={i.id}>
                <span>{i.content}</span>
            </div>
            <div key={i.id}>
                <span>{}</span>
            </div>
            </span> 
        )
    })
) : (
    <p className="center">you have no msg yet</p>
)
```

}

so the kind of output i expect is

```
hello
yes
world
hii
```

Comment: Concat arrays and have sorting done using one object property  and using that single sorted array to bind in dom would be much better approach.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument given to the function given to `map` (`j` in your code example) is the index of the current element, so you can use that to access the right element in the `botMsg` array.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    msg: [{ id: 1, content: "hello" }, { id: 2, content: "world" }],
    botMsg: [{ id: 3, content: "yes" }, { id: 6, content: "hii" }]
  };

  render() {
    const { msg, botMsg } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {msg.map((i, j) => {
          return (
            <span key={i.id}>
              <div>
                <span>{i.content}</span>
              </div>
              <div>
                <span>{botMsg[j].content}</span>
              </div>
            </span>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```